# Steenbrink spectral sequence and modifications of the central fibre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, monodromy

If $f: X \to S$ is a proper map from a complex manifold to a disc, $Y=f^{-1}(0)$ is a divisor with strictly normal crossings and the action of monodromy on $X_t=f^{-1}(t)$ for some (hence any) $t \neq 0$ is unipotent then there exists a spectral sequence, constructed by Steenbrink, that degenerates at $E_2$ and computes the associated graded pieces of the monodromy weight filtration on $H^*(X_t)$. Any modification of $X$ over $S$ that preserves the snc property of the central fibre yields a new spectral sequence that computes the same groups.

Have any explicit quasi-isomorphisms between rows of $E_1$ of the Steenbrink spectral sequences corresponding to some such modifications been worked out? An example of a modification that I have in mind is a blow-up of some intersection of the irreducible components of $Y$, or a blow-up of a smooth subvariety of $Y$ that meets multiple locus transversely.

My question especially pertains to weights >0, since
in weight 0 the corresponding row of the Steenbrink spectral sequence computes singular cohomology of the dual intersection complex of $Y$ and preservation of its homotopy type by many kinds of modifications of $X$ has been studied in the work of Stepanov and others, so I guess one can take quasi-isomorphisms induced by these homotopy equivalences.